# Where in Montreal-Pierre Elliott Trudeau airport are the millimeter-wave body scanners?

Tags: airport-security, x-ray-machines, yul

This [wikipedia page about millimeter-wave scanners](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millimeter_wave_scanner) indicates that Montreal's Pierre Elliott Trudeau airport uses millimeter-wave scanners. Can someone tell me at what sections/terminals of the airport these scanners are used? I couldn't find this information on [the airport's wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montr%C3%A9al-Pierre_Elliott_Trudeau_International_Airport) or with cursory browsing of [the airport's website](http://www.admtl.com/), and I don't know where else to look.

I'm asking in order to be prepared for going through the scanner. I am taking a round-trip later this year to YUL, and I assume the security screening I go through when departing Montreal will be using these machines.

Comment: How do you expect to "be prepared" to go through the scanners?  For most people there is very little difference between going through a millimeter-wave scanner and a normal metal detector.

Comment: Well, this could be many things, but I think it would detract from the core question. One example is that I want to discuss it with my doctor.

Comment: Discussing with your doctor is irrelevant to where the scanners are. Assume you will have to use them, and prepare accordingly, but be aware the health risks appear to be lower than the old scanners - privacy is the thing that is challenged with these new scanners!

Comment: @Doc There actually is, some scanners like this are fully enclosed so if you are claustrophobic it could be a problem.

Comment: Again, the medical implications are not my focus here.

Comment: Could you perhaps reword your question to explain more clearly what you want to know, and why? I mean - the seemingly obvious answer is "in security", but I'm sure you already knew that, so must be asking for some other reason? Are you after the exact GPS coordinates or something??  I'm not terribly surprised there's little mention of it online; airports don't tend to want to describe their security in detail, for obvious reasons.

Comment: You'll probably get a higher dose of radiation from the flight itself that you will going through the scanner

Comment: The medical implications are not my focus here.

Comment: Again, could you say *what* your focus is?  see question of mine above?

Comment: Anyone who has the information I am seeking will be able to post an accurate answer.

Comment: @bneely You are be very evasive.

Answer (score 4):

As of July 2016, there are millimeter wave detectors at every single security lane in Pierre-Elliot-Trudeau airport.

However, you can choose to get patted down instead of going through the scanner. Simply ask the staff before going through.

Answer (score 1):

I presume the question is asking which part of the terminal (ie. to get to which gates) these scanners are used, and possibly even the location within security (left, middle, right) they are located.

I'm presuming this because this was also my initial question when I heard about the introduction of these scanners, as if there's only one at the end of ten or so normal metal detectors then it may be possible to avoid the random lottery by going through an area of security far away from the scanners.

However, as I've found out at SFO several times now, it doesn't appear to be possible to avoid them unless it is particularly busy, as they seem to close down the other 'aisles' when not busy in order to steer you all towards the scanners. On two occasions now, my girlfriend has been directed through the normal metal detector, while I was directed to the scanner, and promptly opted out.

*I'd be interested in hearing what the best arguments for opting out are, as medical (I used this when they were first introduced) and privacy reasons have both gotten snarky remarks/discussions from the security staff (maybe another question for this though)*

Comment: I've now posted [a question about the reasons for opting out](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/6021/2000)

Comment: As clarification, I'm not asking about SFO, and I'm not interested in randomly avoiding the body scanner.

Comment: Sorry, SFO was just my airport of experience, but I assume this practice applies to other US and Canadian airports. Maybe you could give some more information about what exactly you'd like to be prepared for, as it's currently a pretty vague question.